# Change color in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am using this simple example from MSDN
to insert lines in a `RichTextBox`.

```
FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

Run myRun = new Run("This is flow content and you can ");
Bold myBold = new Bold(new Run("edit me!"));

Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myBold);

myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
myRichTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;
```

I want to apply a chosed color to the lines of text, but how to do it?

The `Paragraph` or `Run` classes doesn't have any direct method to change the color.

**EDIT**

I don't want to use all the awkard `SelectionStart`, `SelectionEnd` stuff as posted on the linked post!.

My case is different and is much more simple: the solution posted from **mm8** explains it and is very elegant. 
One single line of code and that is!

Please see the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The `Paragraph` or `Run` classes doesn't have any direct method to change the color.

The `Run` class inherits from `TextElement` and this class has a `Foreground` property that you can set to a `Brush`:

```
Run myRun = new Run("This is flow content and you can ") { Foreground = Brushes.Red };
Bold myBold = new Bold(new Run("edit me!") { Foreground = Brushes.Gray });
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can get/set text color via Foreground property of the rich text box. As bellow example, I changed the text color of rich text box to blue:

```
myRichTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: ok, but I want to be able to apply a different color to each added line of text